# Understanding definition of random variable in textbook "Basic Stochastic Processes"

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, definition, borel-sets

In Zdzislaw Brzezniak and Tomasz Zastawniak, "Basic Stochastic Processes"

A random variable is defined as,

[image]

How do I check the condition

> For 
>   every Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

given that this set is very large?

---

Note: The textbook defines a Borel set as the,
[image]

As a concrete example, let the space $\Omega = \{H,T\}$ denoting Head and Tail respectively. Then the $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ is the set $\mathcal{F} = \{\varnothing, H, T, \{H,T\}\}$

Let's define a random variable which goes from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

$\xi(H) = 1, \xi(T) = -1$

How do I check that $\{\xi \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for every single set in the Borel set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to. There is a measurability criterion (I believe it should be also in the textbook you read): it is enough to check that this is satisfied for any set from a family *generating* $\mathcal{B} (\mathbb R)$ e.g. for $\{(-\infty, x), x\in \mathbb R\} $. Also you don't need to employ the definition each time you need to show the measurability : there are various facts concerning transformations of random variables.